# Objects cannot be resolved

Tags: java, methods

I'm almost done with this program but I am struggling getting over the last hurdle. I'm getting multiple errors, "d1 cannot be resolved", for all my objects down in the "toppTre" method. Can anyone explain to me how I can go about fixing this issue? If it's relevant, that sorting code must be in a method.

```
package mello;
import java.util.*;

public class Resultat {
public static void main(String[] args){

    //Lista med alla deltagare
    Deltagare[] allaDeltagare = new Deltagare[5];

    //Lägger till alla deltagare
    Deltagare d1 = new Deltagare("Loreen", "Statements");
    allaDeltagare[0] = d1;
    d1.setTotRöst(2300, 33092);

    Deltagare d2 = new Deltagare("Anton Hagman", "Kiss You Goodbye");
    allaDeltagare[1] = d2;
    d2.setTotRöst(230650, 33092);

    Deltagare d3 = new Deltagare("Roger Pontare", "Himmel och Hav");
    allaDeltagare[2] = d3;
    d3.setTotRöst(200, 3309);

    Deltagare d4 = new Deltagare("Benjamin Ingrosso", "Good Lovin");
    allaDeltagare[3] = d4;
    d4.setTotRöst(236500, 76092);

    Deltagare d5 = new Deltagare("Lisa Ajax", "I Dont Give A");
    allaDeltagare[4] = d5;
    d5.setTotRöst(2400, 3092);

    toppTre(allaDeltagare);

}

public static void toppTre(Deltagare[] allaDeltagare){
for(int i = 0; i < allaDeltagare.length; i++){
    //Hitta #1
    if((d1.getTotRöst() > d2.getTotRöst()) && (d1.getTotRöst() > d3.getTotRöst()) && (d1.getTotRöst() > d4.getTotRöst()) && (d1.getTotRöst() > d5.getTotRöst())){
        allaDeltagare[0] = d1;
    } else if((d2.getTotRöst() > d1.getTotRöst()) && (d2.getTotRöst() > d3.getTotRöst()) && (d2.getTotRöst() > d4.getTotRöst()) && (d2.getTotRöst() > d5.getTotRöst())){
        allaDeltagare[0] = d2;
    } else if((d3.getTotRöst() > d2.getTotRöst()) && (d3.getTotRöst() > d1.getTotRöst()) && (d3.getTotRöst() > d4.getTotRöst()) && (d3.getTotRöst() > d5.getTotRöst())){
        allaDeltagare[0] = d3;
    } else if((d4.getTotRöst() > d2.getTotRöst()) && (d4.getTotRöst() > d3.getTotRöst()) && (d4.getTotRöst()> d1.getTotRöst()) && (d4.getTotRöst() > d5.getTotRöst())){
        allaDeltagare[0] = d4;
    } else if((d5.getTotRöst() > d2.getTotRöst()) && (d5.getTotRöst() > d3.getTotRöst()) && (d5.getTotRöst() > d4.getTotRöst()) && (d5.getTotRöst() > d1.getTotRöst())){
        allaDeltagare[0] = d5;
    }       


}
System.out.println("#1: " + allaDeltagare[0] + "\n" +
                    "#2 " + "\n" +
                    "#3: " + "ff");
}}
```

Comment: Variables have a *scope*, and you can't reference variables that aren't in scope. Your `d1` and other variables aren't seen inside the `toppTre()` method.

Comment: @Kayaman I understand that but how would I go about solving this issue?

Comment: Well, you're already passing the participants to the method in an array. You shouldn't be even trying to access any `d` variables. What you should fix is the logic in the method. That's a very poor solution, and you can see that it won't be useful at all if you want it to work for 10 or 20 or 50 elements.